# Restart kubernetes pod if a log line exists

Tags: kubernetes

Is there a built-in or elegant way to automatically restart a kubernetes pod if a certain log line is seen in the logs?

Comment: What have you already tried and what outcome is it producing for you? Are the logs on disk, or only going to stdout?

Comment: the elegant way to restart a Pod would be for its livenessProbe to return unhealthy

Answer (score 1):

There is no kind of built-in liveness probe which directly examines the output of `kubectl logs` respectively what the process within your container is writing to `stdout`.

But, if the process of your container writes its log messages to a file or if you are able to redirect the output of the process to a file within the container (e.g., using `tee`, but be aware to properly rotate the file), you can use a liveness probe.

Let's assume, that logs are written to `/var/log/my-service.log` and whenever we observe `time to say good bye`, we need to restart the container.

We can achieve this behavior, by using the following pod spec:

```
spec:
  containers:
  - image: busybox
    name: sf-1102768
    command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "mkdir -p /var/log && echo hello && sleep 60 && echo time to say good bye > /var/log/my-service.log && sleep 3600 && echo hm... still here"]
    livenessProbe:
      exec:
        command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "! grep -q 'time to say good bye' /var/log/my-service.log"]
      initialDelaySeconds: 5
      periodSeconds: 5
```